# Getting the line count and storing in a result set

Tags: shell-script

Need to calculate the number of lines in a file and store it in a resultset.

```
for file in *.csv
do
  num_of_lines=wc -l "$file"
  split -n 5 -d -a 2  "$file" "$file"
done
```

I'm sure I'm wrong in this line: `num_of_lines=wc -l "$file"`. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `num_of_lines` should be,

```
num_of_lines=$(wc -l "$file")
```

to get the output of the word count.

However, the above command prints the file name too. This can be avoided as per @1_CR's comments.

```
num_of_lines=$(< "$file" wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
num_of_lines=$(cat $file | wc -l)
```

Comment: True, but why would you introduce an unnecessary `cat`?

Comment: That also doesn't work if `$file` contains SPC, TAB or newline characters or possibly wildcard characters, or starts with `-`.